# How to use scipy minimize when the constraints are dynamic?

Tags: optimization, scipy, minimize

I have the following optimization problem:

[image]
Where `X` and `q` are endogenous while the other variables are known.

I use scipy minimize function to solve it. I have no problems with the bounds and constraints:

```
# objective function
def objective(q,s):
    return -sumprod(q,s)

def sumprod(l1,l2):
    return sum([x*y for x,y in zip(*[l1,l2])])

# constraints
def cons_periodicflow_min(q):
    return q.sum()-qpmin

con1 = {'type':'ineq','fun':cons_periodicflow_min}


def cons_periodicflow_max(q):
    return qpmax - q.sum()

con2 = {'type':'ineq','fun':cons_periodicflow_max}


def cons_daily_reservoir(q):#xmin,q,X,a,delta):
    return X+a-q-delta-xmin

con3 = {'type':'ineq','fun':cons_daily_reservoir}


def cons_end_reservoir(q):#xend,q,X,a,delta):
    return X[-1]+a[-1]-q[-1]-delta[-1]-xend

con4 = {'type':'ineq','fun':cons_end_reservoir}

cons=[con1,con2,con3,con4]

# definition of the parameters
T=3
q0 = np.zeros(T)
s0 = np.array([10,10,10])
qmin = [0,0,0]
qmax = [10,10,10]
delta = [1,1,1]
a = [2,2,2]
X = [10,0,0]

qpmax = 50
qpmin=10
b = [(qmin[t],qmax[t]) for t in range(T)]

sol = sco.minimize(objective,q0,bounds=b,constraints=cons)
```

My only problem is that `X` depends on `q` so I need to update X at each time step, can I add it to the minimize function? Else how to do it?

EDIT:

I can express `X` in the following way (please don't mind the t / t+1 issues):

[image]

Therefore the constraint with `Xmin` can rewrites:

[image]

Does it help to express the optimisation problem?

Comment: Looks to me like you need to introduce variables for ```X``` too. Instead of solely optimizing over ```q``` you will want to optimize over ```[q,X]``` (in terms of API usage this is always a flat vector). Additionally, you need constraints describing the dynamic relations, e.g. ```x[1] = x[0] + a[0] - q[0] - delta[0]```. Care has to be taken about ```Xmin``` though, as you want a *smooth* formulation.

Comment: If I am not mistaken this is an LP.

Comment: @sascha Are you sure we need to optimize over W as well? How would you introduce this in the objective function?

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen I don't know what an LP is. How would you solve this?

Comment: My approach was to introduce aux-vars to describe X (w?). If there is some inter-play between those and q (decision-vars), these are decision-variables too (if not a-priori set). They do not necessarily be part of the objective (zeros only). Look up what an LP (Linear Program) is to reason about your problem (which really looks like an LP). Solving an LP with scipy's minimize will be less fast and less robust compared to an actual LP-solver (two available in scipy: ```optimize.linprog(method='...')```.

Comment: @sascha Thank you I believe I get your point, I edited my post, does it help? How can I integrate it in the optimization part? Thank you for the meaning of "LP".

Comment: A linear program (LP) is an optimization model where the objective function and all constraints are linear. LP models are typically solved with LP solvers (a good LP solver can handle problems with millions of variables and constraints). You are now solving it with an NLP (nonlinear programming) solver. The description is vague about which quantities are endogenous  (to be determined by the model) and which ones are exogenous (determined outside the model: constants). I suspect the only endogenous decision variables are X and q. This would make the problem indeed an LP.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen Thanks a lot, I looked at LP and found out that indeed it is one. Using linprog would therefore makes more sense. You are right only X and q are endogenous, but I cannot figure out how to rewrite the problem so that I solve it with linprog. Do you have any idea?

Comment: There are some examples in the docs that are worthwhile studying..